# How to get system volume level as a scalar from 0 to 100?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, volume

I'm currently working on a "Volume mixer" to control the volume of each program on my PC (Windows 10).

How do I get the volume level of each program/audio session as a scalar from 0 to 100?

As you can see, in the code below, I found the `GetPeakValue` function, but it returns values like 0.0812654 or 0.021352.

I'm sure that these values are the volume of each audio session in a scalar from 1.0 to 0.0. But what I want is the volume limitation, which you can set in the windows audio mixer for example, and not the current level. So if I set the program volume level to 50%, I want a value like 0.5.

In the second function (`getVolume`), you'll see that I already got the master volume in a 0-100 scalar, but there the endpoint device has a function for the scalar level already. So I'll need the same function at least, or a calculation, to get such a scalar for every audio session as well.

```
void getSessions() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IMMDeviceEnumerator *pDeviceEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice *pDevice = NULL;
    IAudioSessionManager2 *pAudioSessionManager2 = NULL;
    IAudioSessionEnumerator *pAudioSessionEnumerator = NULL;

    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&pDeviceEnumerator);
    pDeviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);

    pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void **) &pAudioSessionManager2);
    pAudioSessionManager2->GetSessionEnumerator(&pAudioSessionEnumerator);

    int nSessionCount;
    pAudioSessionEnumerator->GetCount(&nSessionCount);

    std::cout << "Session Count: " << nSessionCount << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        for (int nSessionIndex = 0; nSessionIndex < nSessionCount; nSessionIndex++) {
            IAudioSessionControl *pSessionControl = NULL;
            if (FAILED(pAudioSessionEnumerator->GetSession(nSessionIndex, &pSessionControl)))
                continue;

            IAudioMeterInformation *pAudioMeterInformation = NULL;
            pSessionControl->QueryInterface(&pAudioMeterInformation);

            float fPeak = NULL;
            pAudioMeterInformation->GetPeakValue(&fPeak);

            std::cout << "fPeak Value: " << fPeak << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}

double getVolume() {
    float currentVolume = 0;

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
    IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;
    deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
    deviceEnumerator->Release();
    deviceEnumerator = NULL;

    IAudioEndpointVolume *endpointVolume = NULL;
    defaultDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume);
    defaultDevice->Release();
    defaultDevice = NULL;

    float fLevel;
    endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&fLevel);
    qDebug() << "FLevel: ";
    qDebug() << fLevel;

    endpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&currentVolume);
    endpointVolume->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return (double)(currentVolume * 100);
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about what the range of values it returns is, but look up the standard "map range" equation. It's used to convert a number from one range (say 0-1) to another range (like 0-100). You'll need to know what the range it uses first is though. Also note, that if it is something as simple as being in a range of 0-1, you can always just multiply it by 100.

Comment: Yeah sure, I've already tried to multiply the value with 100, but there you get values like 8.12 or 2.13 (with the examples above). My Master volume is 50% and so the program too. So the value should be 50% or 25% (cause the master volume is on 50%). If I'm not that stupid, of course.

Already tried some other calculations, nothing works as expected, which doesn't necessarily mean that this values are wrong. 

I've already tried to get the Master volume level without scalar, but there I get a value of -10.5467574 which can't be right either.

But thanks for your comment

Comment: Mmm...  It's almost like the volumes are in deciBels of attenuation, which is quite common in the audio world.  The -10 is a strong hint.  Check your values against a dB to float calculator...  http://www.playdotsound.com/portfolio-item/decibel-db-to-float-value-calculator-making-sense-of-linear-values-in-audio-tools/

Comment: I tried to calculate 0.0358267 to Float and get 1.004133219555603.

So that can't be right either, I guess. Even if it's right and these values are in dB, they are still the current volume. If I start a video or music file and watch the console output, I get different values every second from that function. So it's the current volume in dB probably, as you said. But what I want is the "limitation mark" from the windows audio/volume mixer, which is set to 50%, in my case (Master vol: 50%, program vol(google chrome for example): 50%). But good idea that it's probably be in dB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I've found the solution for my problem!

I had to call QueryInterface on the SessionControl to gain access to ISimpleAudioVolume where you can use the functions GetMasterVolume and SetMasterVolume. It's a 0-1 scalar, but you can just multiply it with 100 to get a 0-100 scalar. If the system's master volume is on 50%, you get a output of 1 if the program volume is on 50% too, so the output is based on the system's master volume!

Thanks for every comment and help!

Here the working code:

```
void getSessions() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IMMDeviceEnumerator *pDeviceEnumerator;
    IMMDevice *pDevice;
    IAudioSessionManager2 *pAudioSessionManager2;
    IAudioSessionEnumerator *pAudioSessionEnumerator;

    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&pDeviceEnumerator);
    pDeviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);

    pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void **) &pAudioSessionManager2);
    pAudioSessionManager2->GetSessionEnumerator(&pAudioSessionEnumerator);

    int nSessionCount;
    pAudioSessionEnumerator->GetCount(&nSessionCount);

    while (true) {
        for (int nSessionIndex = 0; nSessionIndex < nSessionCount; nSessionIndex++) {
            IAudioSessionControl *pSessionControl;
            if (FAILED(pAudioSessionEnumerator->GetSession(nSessionIndex, &pSessionControl)))
                continue;

            ISimpleAudioVolume *pSimpleAudioVolume;
            pSessionControl->QueryInterface(&pSimpleAudioVolume);

            float fLevel;
            pSimpleAudioVolume->GetMasterVolume(&fLevel);

            std::cout << "fLevel Value: " << fLevel << std::endl;
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```